# HTML5 Game - Disable multi touch such that two buttons can't be pressed at once

Tags: html, multi-touch

I am developing a web based mobile game, using CreateJS / Canvas / HTML5 for the main rendering.

The buttons on my game are all constructed with DOM based `<a/>` tags.

The problems arise when two buttons are pressed at exactly the same time, which causes unexpected behaviour in the game.

I have tried to bind to touchstart method to disable all other buttons, but if it's at exactly the same time, this appears to not have the desired effect.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just to confirm-only one button can be pressed at one time??